# What direction are the decay particles of muons emitted in?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos

If I were to run an experiment where I could measure the neutrino as well as the positron emitted when a muon decays, what direction should i be looking in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decay of a (anti-)muon to a positron is
$$ \mu^+ \longrightarrow e^+ + \nu_e + \bar{\nu}_\mu .$$
As there are three light decay products their directions (in the rest frame of the anti-muon) are only weakly correlated.

The usual experimental procedure for dealing with this is to work with a beam of highly relativistic (anti-)muons so that all the decay products go in roughly the direction of the (anti-)muon beam. This also has the advantage of increasing the neutrino interaction cross-section up to a level where it is merely tiny rather than well-nigh-infinitesimal.

All that said, even a very small and basic muon-neutrino measurement requires a considerable accelerator, a custom focusing system called a "horn", and a highly specialized detector system. It's not really suitable for a one-person project, nor for a hobbyist budget.

Comment: This is assuming I have access to a particle accelerator.

Comment: Also in regards to your comment about the change in direction at relativistic speeds, assuming my muons are travelling at 0.98-0.99c what are the changes going to be from fermis golden rule, I'm looking more for the likely locations in a 3d space

Comment: You can get a decent BoTE number for the apex angle of the beam cone by assuming a transverse momentum of $\approx 50 \,\mathrm{MeV}$ (about half the muon mass, right?) in the muon rest frame and then boosting to the lab frame. In practice these things are Monte Carlo'ed.